# How to parse a XML converted to JSON

Tags: jquery, xml, json, xml-parsing, nodelist

I have get an xml file from a WebService

```
<MasterProducts> <MasterProduct> <Productcode>023DDC</Productcode> <Description>Dell CRT 17 Computer Monitor E771a</Description> <ThumbPic>NoImage.png</ThumbPic> <RRP>0.000000</RRP> <Stock>2</Stock> </MasterProduct> </MasterProducts>
```

The Chrome IDE I use automatically converts this to JSON, I've been trying to parse this without any success as I am quite new to Javascript.

The httpResponse returns an error variable and a data variable which holds the json file.

```
if(error===false)
{ 
    if(data !== '')
    { 
        objData = data.getElementsByTagName('MasterProducts');
        //returns a NodeList here
        var items = objData[0].getElementsByTagName('MasterProduct')[0].getElementsByTagName('Description')[0].firstChild.data;

    }
    else
    { 
        alert("No Data"); 
    } 
}
```

I have only gone as far as getting the nodelist but I haven't been able to get the data I need from the tags.

EDIT:
Using an online converter I've gotten the JSON below

```
{
   "MasterProducts": {
      "MasterProduct": {
  "Productcode": "023DDC",
  "Description": "Dell CRT 17 Computer Monitor E771a",
  "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
  "RRP": "0.000000",
  "Stock": "2"
      }
  }
 }
```

Comment: could you add the JSON or at least a sample similar to it?

Comment: you don't need to use getElementsByTagName when working with json.  just access the data directly with dot notation ie... var items = data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct.whatever.whatever

Comment: What happens when I have several sets of results I need to populate an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you're getting back is valid, according to http://jsonlint.com/, so your script should be able to access the contents of data using dot notation, rather than having to parse nodes as with XML

```
var data ={
            "MasterProducts": {
                "MasterProduct": {   
                    "Productcode": "023DDC",
                    "Description": "Dell CRT 17 Computer Monitor E771a",
                    "ThumbPic": "NoImage.png",
                    "RRP": "0.000000",
                    "Stock": "2"
                 }   
             }  
         }

 var description = data.MasterProducts.MasterProduct.Description;
```

description will contain "Dell CRT 17 Computer Monitor E771a"

Answer (score 0):

The data seems to be a type of string. "getElementsByTagName" is only available (in some browsers) on the dom element and the dom itself. Try adding your response to a hidden div and query it using jQuery.

```
$("#hidden").html(data);
```

Then query that div using jquery or you can use the dom directly as you are trying to do.

```
$("#hidden").find("MasterProducts")[0].getElementsByTagName("MasterProduct")
```

Comment: This should work in chrome. Would you like me to create a fiddle?

Comment: Yes please, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can store your xml directly in a jQuery obj without adding it to the dom, like the other answer says.

```
var $xml = $(data);
```

Then simply use jQuery to target specific elements, avoid using getElementsByTagName, as it is only available in certain browsers.

```
var MasterProducts = [];

$xml.find('MasterProduct').each(function(){
   var $masterProduct = $(this);
   var masterProduct = {};
   $masterProduct.find('*').each(function(){
      masterProduct[$(this).get(0).tagName] = $(this).text();
   });
   MasterProducts.push(masterProduct);
});
```

In the end your MasterProducts array should contain a JavaScript object which you can then convert to JSON with the following call.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(MasterProducts);
```

I put this on jsFiddle.  See http://jsfiddle.net/WRF4D/